# Docker Container Not Able to Find Updated Node Modules

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, nestjs

1. I ***updated a node module*** in my project [1] (a NestJs server)
2. My `package.json` and my `package-lock.json` both look correct [2]
3. When I run the ***server locally it works***
4. I rebuilt the docker image, and after the server failed, tried to rebuild `docker build --no-cache -t myApp .`

What could be the reason that when I ***run the docker image*** `docker-compose up` I am still seeing the ***error***:

```
Cannot find module 'aws-sdk' or its corresponding type declarations.
1 import { config } from 'aws-sdk';
```

### my `dockerfile`

```
FROM node:12.13-alpine as development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=development
COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM node:12.13-alpine as production
ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=production
COPY . .
COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist
CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

### my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  main:
    container_name: main
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - ${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}
      - 9229:9229
    command: npm run start:dev
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - webnet
    depends_on:
      - ${POSTGRES_DOCKER_HOST}
  main_db:
    container_name: ${POSTGRES_DOCKER_HOST}
    image: postgres:12
    restart: always
    networks:
      - webnet
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      PG_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '${POSTGRES_PORT}:${POSTGRES_PORT}'
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
networks:
  webnet:
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

---

### Footnotes

1. `npm install aws-sdk`
2. `package.json`

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@types/aws-sdk": "^2.7.0",
  "aws-sdk": "^2.792.0",
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `docker-compose.yml` file specifies

```
volumes:
  - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

This creates an *anonymous volume* that holds the `node_modules` directory.  The very first time your application runs, the volume is populated from the `node_modules` directory in the image.  After that, the contents of the volume take precedence over the contents of the image.  This line essentially tells Docker to ignore changes in the image's `node_volumes` directory; it is not a pass-through to the image to ignore the outer bind mount.

In the Dockerfile you show, you're not really getting any benefits from the volume mounts at all, and I'd recommend deleting the entire `volumes:` block.  (The `node dist/main` command will not do live reloading, and since you're running the built `dist` tree, edits in `src/main.js` won't appear without an explicit rebuild anyways.)

Comment: Thank you! I got it to run. I have 2 questions. 1. why didn't it work even after I rebuilt the project? I would have thought that the new build would override the `node_modules` in the docker image. (My understanding was my `build` command in the `docker-compose` file was buidling `RUN npm install --only=development` so that it should match my local installation for development) 2. Why do you say it's not live reloading? It does seem when I update a file I get the message `File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...` and the server does restart...

Comment: The design point for volumes is to hold user data that needs to be preserved across updates, so the `node_modules` anonymous volume overrides what's in the image, even if the image changes.

Comment: The `CMD` in the Dockerfile isn't a live-reloading variant, but now that I'm looking at the `docker-compose.yml` again, I see you also override `command:`.  That would in fact get you a live-reloading environment, but you're not really using any parts from the original image at all.

Answer (score 0):

In your Dockerfile use `npm install` without the `--only=development` option, as aws-sdk is in your dependencies and will not be installed (see the non cli reference for the behaviour of the `only` flag: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install).
Also, any additional typings should be installed as de dependency rather than as dependency. This way the typings will not be installed for your production build as they are not needed anymore after the build.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification! In the footnotes to my question you can see I did run `npm install aws-sdk` however, you make a good point: all typings should be dev dependencies; however, if you see the accepted answer, it explained that the anonymous volume to hold the `node_modules` was preventing them from ever getting updated (although, I asked a follow up question, because it's not entirely clear). I think you are correct though that if I use the install with the `only-development` flag for modules I don't want in production this should solve the issue of not having them copied over.